# Is it possible to combine a color and a image with gradients?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I want to have a split background with a color on the left side and a image on the right side and both should be equally big(50% each). So I know I can style the body like this to get red on 50% left of the body and blue on the right side:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red 50%, blue 50%, blue);
```

I would instead want something like this:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red 50%, url('image.jpg') 50%, url('image.jpg'));
```

Is this possible or should I take another approach?

I know I can split it up to two divs and make them take up 50% each and set whatever background I want on them but I want to have a navbar that is transparent and it should go from left all the way to the right so that's the problem with having two divs.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, red 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%), url('image.jpg');
```

Comment: That kinda worked but now the image is just like a background image for the whole body. I want the image to be the background of only the right side. Is that possible?

Comment: It would be easier for me to help you if you put all your code

Comment: `background-size: cover;` ?

Comment: Tried that but that still makes it cover the whole body and not only the 50% on the right.

Comment: `background-size: 100%, 50% 100%;` But it will stretch the image

Comment: That stretched the image in a weird way. But this worked without stretching the image: `background-size: 100%, 50%;` the problem now is that the image is not the right height, it only takes up like 80% of the height

Comment: An image has a fixed size. It will be complicated to get what you want without stretching, cropping or scaling the image

Comment: Yeah I know, Is there anyway to crop it to the left? So make the height cover the whole page and then crop the excess width out to the left? If you understand what I mean, tell me otherwise and I'll try and explain better

Comment: It depends on the image, but you can cheat by adapting the background-size example : 
`    background-size: 100% auto, 80%;
`

(I don't see your image on your fiddle so I can't be especially precise)

Comment: yeah but then it crops the left side of the image, is there any way to crop the right side out instead?

Comment: background-position: -150%

Comment: Didn't work, but this answer is right anyways, you answered how to make one side with color and the other with an image, I'll keep trying to position the image right. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both together with commas as `linear-gradient` uses the `background-image` css property, but using a background image and linear gradient like this seems like the hard way of making this work. If you make an absolute positioned inner container in the nav a with a width of 100% and add two divs inside, those divs can both be 50% and then you can style each accordingly. Make sure the parent element is `position: relative` so you can set `z-index` to make the inner-container sit underneath your nav elements. Below is a sample of how it could work. Hope this helps.

Example

```css
nav {
  height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.inner-container {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   display: flex;
   opacity: 0.5;
   z-index: 0;
}
.inner-container > div {
   flex: 1 1 50%;
}
#blue-box {
    background: linear-gradient(#e66465, #9198e5);
}
#img-box {
    background: url(https://teamroboboogie.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/campo_logo_lrg.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div id="blue-box">

    </div>
    <div id="img-box">

    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>This could be a button</li><!--
 --><li>This could be a button</li><!--
 --><li>This could be a button</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do you mean that the `#blue-box` and `#img-box` is the two backgrounds?

Comment: okay I understand. This may work but then the `nav`needs to be `height: 100vh`because the background image should cover the whole height

Comment: You could even set the container outside the nav and make the nav transparent. That way you could work with the two separately. The container could be absolutely positioned with a negative `z-index`.